# How do I remove a failing disk from a LSI MegaRAID disk group?

Tags: lsi, megaraid, storcli

One of the disks in group 0 (EID:Slot 252:4, DiskID 12) is starting to fail it's smart tests:

```
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       1837
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       57
```

but I can't find any documentation how to *remove* disks from a disk group.

Do I have to

```
storcli /c0/e252/s4 set offline
```

or rather

```
storcli /c0/e252/s4 spindown
```

or both? What's the difference between "spindown" and "offline"? What about

```
storcli /c0/s4 set missing
```

What does that do? What does "missing" mean?

And how about the rebuild? Does that start automatically?

If not, then I guess the "start rebuild" command is my friend but why do I have to specify a single disk for that? It would make much more sense to specify the disk group or volume to rebuild, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.45drives.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_do_I_replace_a_failed_drive_with_LSI_9280_cards%3F, the correct sequence is:

```
storcli /c0/e252/s4 set offline
storcli /c0/e252/s4 set missing
storcli /c0/eall/s4 spindown     // Note: /eall instead of /e252. No idea why.
```

After the first command, the output of `storcli /c0/e252/s4` should show `Offln`. After the last command, it was `UGood` (Unconfigured Good) for me.

Note that the second command (`set missing`) failed for me.

Afterwards, the rebuild should start if you have a dedicated or global hot spare (DHS or GHS) and enabled automatic rebuild. To verify this, run

```
storcli /c0/eall/sall show rebuild
```

That will print something like this:

```
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Show Drive Rebuild Status Succeeded.


----------------------------------------------------------
Drive-ID    Progress% Status          Estimated Time Left 
----------------------------------------------------------
/c0/e252/s0 -         Not in progress -                   
/c0/e252/s1 -         Not in progress -                   
/c0/e252/s2 -         Not in progress -                   
/c0/e252/s3 -         Not in progress -                   
/c0/e252/s4 -         Not in progress -                   
/c0/e252/s6 18        In progress     -                   
/c0/e252/s7 -         Not in progress -                   
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the value "In progress" for slot 6 (s6). The second column gives you the percentage of the rebuild (18%).

I'm using this small script to monitor progress:

```
while true ; do clear ; date ; storcli /c0/e252/s6 show rebuild ; sleep 5 ; done
```

To locate the failed drive, you can use this command:

```
storcli /c0/e252/s4 start locate
```

That should make the indicator light of your drive blink.

Comment: you could use `watch -n 5 storcli /c0/e252/s6 show rebuild` for the same effect